# Magento Commerce Cloud 2.3 which template(s) for products displayed by page builder

Tags: template, products, magento-2-commerce, page-builder

In my custom theme I need to modify the product list/grid templates for products that were placed there using the page builder.
Can anyone please tell me where I can find these template files? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right templates. The page builder uses the templates from the catalog-widget module.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your files here

Layout files 
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/View/frontend/layout/`

Templates files
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/View/frontend/templates/`

It is not a good practice to do direct edit in magento's core files
If you wish to customise it,  then you should first create your own module and then you can do your changes in that. 
If you wanna create your own module please check out this [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not need the "normal" product template files. I need the templates files for products that I have added to the category page via the page builder. In the page builder module I do not find them and also not in the catalog module.